# Profiling TCL/TK information explanation

Tags: tcl, profiling

I'm looking for information on the data :

```
Profiling information for ::isect_lineplane
============================================================
            Total calls:  938
    Caller distribution:
  ::IntersectionPoint:  938
           Compile time:  378
          Total runtime:  141009
        Average runtime:  150
          Runtime StDev:  31
         Runtime cov(%):  20.7
  Total descendant time:  57009
Average descendant time:  60
Descendants:
  ::add_v3v3:  938
  ::dot_v3v3:  1876
  ::mul_v3:  938
  ::sub_v3v3:  1876
```

I use [profiler Tcllib](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/profiler/profiler.html), but I do not understand the out information. In particular :

- **Compile time**
- **Average runtime**
- **Runtime StDev**
- **Total descendant time**
- **Average descendant time**

Can you explain to me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Compile time: Tcl procedures are compiled to byte code the first time they are called. This is the run time of the procedure for the first call, which includes the time taken by compilation.
- Average runtime: over a number of calls, this is the average time it takes to run the procedure.
- Runtime StDev: this is the standard deviation parameter of the runtime value. If you know statistics, this number will tell you more than if you don't. Basically, the smaller this number is, the less variation in runtime.
- Total descendant time: descendants are procedures called by this procedures, and the procedures they call, and so on. This is the amount of time spent executing descendant procedures.
- Average descendant time: and this is the average.